# Datasore Admin: Entity Deletion Not Finishing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I started an appengine delete operation for seven entity kinds. Total size is about 6Mb. For more than 2 hours now, it still shows me "1 completed, 6 active". Of course this is not the first time I clear data on appengine and it doesn't take this long. We're doing rapid development and now I can't upload code for for our client developers to test against.
Please I want to know if this is normal or if there was something I did wrong or if appengine just hated us and wanted to screw us. Also, I'll like to know what to do (wait forever, initiate another delete, delete the appengine generated active job entities, etc).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. It turned out we ran out of quota (we've not enabled billing). I never knew that "delete" also counts in the quota usage.